# Git pull not updating the last commit from remote

Tags: git, git-pull

On the remote master, the repo has 3 commits ahead my local commit. I am trying to pull the latest commit.

```
$git checkout master
$git pull origin master
Current branch master is up to date.
```

then I have tried fetch

```
$git fetch origin master:master
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also tried reclone this repo, but I still lost last 3 commits. Please let me know if you need provide any more information. Thanks for helping.

Comment: can you share log details? Just do:  git log.
It would give list of commits. 
I suppose there are clashes that needs to be fixed. If there is nothing new on your local, you can delete local copy of master and recreate it

Comment: Are you sure `origin` points to the right repository that has 3 new commits? Are you sure the new commits are at the head of branch `master`?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you instead of
$ git pull
Type
$ git pull [remote] [local-branch> </code]Iit works if you instead of
$ git pull

```
$ git pull [remote] [local-branch> </code]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can paste the output of  "git status" , "git log --graph --decorate --all" as additional input.

Comment: *`git fetch origin master:master` this syntax is not right* There is nothing wrong with the syntax, it's just not for the currently checked out branch.

Comment: *`git pull origin master` should get the latest from remote repo.* But it didn't. The OP showed that by running the command.

Comment: `git fetch origin master:master` as the error message: `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository`

Comment: *paste the screen snapshot* Please, no. [We don't like screenshots](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), they're hard to read, and it's impossible to copy text from them. Please paste text!

Comment: It's not an error about syntax, the error is about refusing to update the current branch. Any other branch can be fetched that way.

Comment: @phd, yes, I verified that you are right, `git fetch origin master:master` works if the current branch is other than `master`. thanks.